# Sort word sequence with pointers c++

Tags: c++, pointers

first question on stackoverflow , i need to sort a sequence of words with pointers, can anyone help me? 
-Not sure it's ok nod_curent->NOD_urmator->word

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <cstring>

struct NOD
{
    char word[20];
    struct NOD *NOD_next;
};

void sort_list(struct NOD *prim)
{
    char tmp[50];
    struct NOD *nod_curent;    

    nod_curent=prim;

    while(nod_curent!=NULL||nod_curent->NOD_urmator!=NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(nod_curent->cuvant,nod_word->NOD_urmator->word)>0)
        {
            strcpy(tmp,nod_curent->word);
            strcpy(nod_curent->word,nod_curent->NOD_urmator->word);
            strcpy(nod_curent->NOD_urmator->word,tmp);
        }
        nod_curent=nod_curent->NOD_urmator;
    }

    while(nod_curent!=NULL)
    {
        printf(" %s\n", nod_curent->cuvant);
        nod_curent=nod_curent->NOD_urmator;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like C, but as you explicitly ask for C++, I removed the wrong tag.

Comment: Can you explain what error you have or what the expected result is?

Answer (score 1):

1) what about `NOD_urmator`? You use it but it's undefined in `NOD`. It's the same as `NOD_next`?

2) what about `cuvant`? You use it but it's undefined in `NOD`. It's the same as `word`?

3) what about `nod_word`? You use it but it's undefined in `sort_list()`. It's the same as `nod_curent`?

4) the following test is wrong (I suppose) and dangerous (I'm sure)

```
while(nod_curent!=NULL||nod_curent->NOD_urmator!=NULL)
```

because if `nod_curent` is `NULL` fail the first condition (`nod_curent!=NULL`), so the "`||`" condition imply that it's tested the second one (`nod_curent->NOD_urmator!=NULL`) but with `nod_curent == NULL` you're dereferencing a null pointer. Crash!

You're intention was to use "and" operator ?

```
while ( (nod_curent != NULL) && (nod_curent->NOD_urmator != NULL) )
```

that it's the same as

```
while ( nod_curent && nod_curent->NOD_urmator )
```